# Passing parameters to WCF using RestSharp

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, restsharp

I have the following WCF service:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string UpdateReturnedPatients(string lst);
```

And I am calling it using RestSharp like this:

```
Ids id = new Ids();
id.id = "EMR0037933";

var client = new RestClient("https://myweb.com/services/Service1.svc");

var request = new RestRequest("UpdateReturnedPatients", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id);

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

request.AddParameter("lst", json);
// execute the request
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
```

But when I run the code, I have this returned:

Request Error:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. The
>   exception message is 'The incoming message has an unexpected message
>   format 'Raw'. The expected message formats for the operation are
>   'Xml', 'Json'. This can be because a WebContentTypeMapper has not been
>   configured on the binding.

What is the problem, and how I can pass the parameter (in my case named lst) to the web-service?

**I can use methods other than RestSharp.**

> UPDATE
>   Changed web service to:

```
   [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "UpdateReturnedPatients", RequestFormat =
     WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    string   UpdateReturnedPatients(Ids lst);
```

and The implementation of it is

```
   public string UpdateReturnedPatients(Ids lst)
    {

        try
        {

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst);

            return json;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }


    }
```

And I used

```
request.AddBody(new { lst = id});
```

instead of AddParameter()
but the response is :
"{\"id\":null}"
It is not returning the value of the id field, even though I did supply it.

Comment: 1) I think your service should also accept object as a parameter. 2) Don't serialize before calling `AddParameter`

Comment: What you mean by accepting object? I removed the serializing and got the same error.

Comment: I mean instead of string `UpdateReturnedPatients(string lst);` try `string UpdateReturnedPatients(Ids lst);`

Comment: @MikeMakarov Thank you, but I still got error I updated the question please check